# What is the proper way to read hexadecimal values using GetPrivateProfileInt, GetPrivateProfileString?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, types

Right now i want to get values from variables inside a ini and spit them out on a sendkey function. So currently this is how i have them defined in the top obviously incorrect since i get the default value when i test the variable.

```
const int KeyAtk = GetPrivateProfileInt(L"BotSettings",L"AttackKey", 0xA2, L"config.ini");
const int KeyLoot = GetPrivateProfileInt(L"BotSettings",L"LootKey", 0x5A, L"config.ini");
//Counts
int CntAtk = GetPrivateProfileInt(L"BotSettings",L"PressAttack", 25, L"config.ini");
int CntLoot = GetPrivateProfileInt(L"BotSettings",L"PressLoot", 15, L"config.ini");
```

The Values with const int infront of them have a hexadecimal value like 0xA2 and 0x5A which are just Virtual-Key Codes. I want to beable to change this key at anytime thats why i didn't just use it in the sendkey function anyone with ideas on how to get GetPrivateProfileInt to read the hexadecimal values.

Comment: What are those functions from? winapi? if yes, maybe adding the appropriate tag would be useful.

Comment: Those functions are from winapi.

Comment: The question or your doubt is little unclear to me. Do you want to read the "value" in "const int KeyAtk" which is "Hex" in your INI file? Cuz that I have compiled and it is working perfectly. You can show us a section of your INI file and the output you want.

Comment: Gosh, you aren't still meant to be calling those functions. They went out of style back in the 20th century.

Comment: Sorry, what's your actual question?

Answer (score 2):

`GetPrivateProfileInt` does not support hexadecimal. If you want to support hexadecimal, you'll have to call `GetPrivateProfileString` and parse it yourself.

Comment: and [`StrToIntEx(..., STIF_SUPPORT_HEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is an easy way to parse